# I'm trying to count the number of distinct pairs but I get error

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, list

I have recently decided to start solving coding problems and I'm struggled with this 'Counting pairs' problem for two days now.

The problems says that two pais of integers (a,b) and (c,d) are considered distinct if at least one element of (a,b) is not in (c,d) (For example; givien a list (1,3,3,4), (1,3) is distinct from (1,4) and (3,4) but not from (1,3) with 2 chosen from a different index in the list. A pair is valid if a<=b !

So I have to write a function that returns the count of valid pairs in my list that have a specified difference X ( a + X = b )

```
def countPairs(liste, X):
    # Write your code here
    count = 0
    liste.sort()
    j=0
    d=0
    while d<len(liste):
        if liste[d]-liste[j]==X:
            count=count+1
            j=j+1
            d=d+1
        elif liste[d]-liste[j]>X:
            j=j+1
        else:
            d=d+1
    return count
```

Thank you !

Comment: What error did you get? Please don't just allude to an error. Say what it is, and in what line it occurs.

Comment: It doesn't work for all test cases.

Comment: What test case or cases doesn't it pass? What did you do to try and debug it? Please give a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You do not check for *distinct* pairs in your solution. See what will happen when `liste = [1, 1, 3, 3]` and `X = 2`. You will count the two pairs, one with elements with indices (0,2) and other (1,3).

To omit the duplicates you may use a data structure that does not allow them: [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html). You can convert between the data structures like that:

```
set(liste)
list(set(liste))
```

I suppose the assumption is that `X >= 0`.

Comment: yes, u're correct! i'm lost how to check for distinct pairs tho

Comment: @prepari , if I managed to help, please accept the answer